# Convert query from SQL to Entity Framework code first approach

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I want to convert my SQL query into Entity Framework code-first but unable to do it.

This is my SQL query

```
select * from tests where id in(select testid from PatientTests where PatientId=@id)
```

This is Test Model from this model I want to fetch records.

```
public class Tests
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Test Name")]
    public string TestName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Short Name")]
    public string  ShortName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Technical Name")]
    public string  TechName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Test Price")]
    public float TestPrice { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sub Department")]
    public int SubDeptId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Center")]
    public int CenterId { get; set; }

    public string Separate { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Sub Department")]
    [ForeignKey("SubDeptId")]
    //relation of departments table
    public virtual SubDepartments subDepartments { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Centers")]
    [ForeignKey("CenterId")]
    //relation of departments table
    public virtual Centers centers  { get; set; }

}
```

this is patient tests model

```
 public class PatientTest
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Patient Id")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Test Id")]
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Doctor")]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Center")]
    public int CenterId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Test")]
    [ForeignKey("TestId")]
    //relation of Tests table
    public virtual Tests Tests { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Doctor Reference")]
    [ForeignKey("DoctorId")]
    //relation of Doctors table
    public virtual Doctors Doctors { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Center Reference")]
    [ForeignKey("CenterId")]
    //relation of Centers table
    public virtual Centers Centers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Patient")]
    [ForeignKey("PatientId")]
    //relation of Patient table
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }

}
```

So I want record from tests table where id should be matched with patientTest table testid and only given patient Id record must be fetch.

Comment: Can you show us what your models look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Tests` model seems to be missing a navigation property to `PatientTest`. It can still be done though.

Guessing a bit here for how your context properties are named.

```cs
var tests = context.PatientTests
                   .Where(pt => pt.PatientId == patientId)
                   .Select(pt => pt.Tests)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: getting error here in Where(p => p.PatientId = id)
error is "Cannot implicitly convert type int to bool"

Comment: Edited, it was supposed to be `==` and not `=`

Comment: now getting exception in SelectMany()
Argument Null Exception

Comment: Try replacing it with Select

Comment: It's not working getting an error
does not contain a definition for 'Tests'

Comment: Your model says that `PatientTest` has a property called `Tests`. Please update if that is not the case.